# MS Reporting Services SSRS - Is there any kind of repository to view report meta data?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

needless to say that i´m new to SSRS. I want to collect meta data for a set of reports in the SSRS and hoped that there exists some kind of repository or dictionary where i can query let´s say information like

- creation date
- subscribers
- last run

and stuff like that.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet for all of these sorts of queries is the **ReportServer** database, which stores all sorts of Report Server metadata in its tables.

See [Report Server Database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156016.aspx).

The main hurdle is that Microsoft doesn't document these tables for whatever reason, but they aren't so complex that you can't figure them out, plus there are plenty of blog posts available.

Looking at your subscriptions example, you can use a query like:

```
select [Owner] = u.UserName
  , LastModifiedBy = um.UserName
  , s.ModifiedDate
  , s.LastRunTime
  , s.LastStatus
from Subscriptions s
  inner join Users u on s.OwnerID = u.UserID
  inner join Users um on s.ModifiedByID = um.UserID
```

Comment: Perfect. I supposed something like that has to be there, now i´m sure, thanks a lot